# Regular expression for finding all dots on left side of string

Tags: regex

I want to find all dots of each line but only on the left side of the "=".
These are my samples:

```
"key.other.this.sample" = "I am the localized text."
"key.other.this.sample.with.more" = "I am the sample URL with www.sample.com"
"key.other.this.sample.with.more" = "I am the sample wit a \nline break"
```

I tried it with the following:

```
((\.{1})(?!")(?! )(?!(com))(?!(\n))).*(?<=(=))
```

This delivers me the right result but it checks the whole line instead of just checking the left side of the "=".

Can this achieved with "look behind"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you doing this? What is the tool/environment? There may be no need for lookarounds here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dot this with a lookbehind assertion, but only when an (in)finite quantifier is supported:

```
(?<=^[^=\n]*)\.
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<=` Poaitive lookbehind, assert that what is to the left is

  - `^[^=\n]*` Assert the start of the string, and the  optionall match any character except a newline or an equals sign
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `\.` Match a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KCcZ5Q/1)

A pcre based pattern could be to skip all after the first equals sign

```
=.*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KHDWZU/1)

Comment: These two solutions are safe, the only unknown is OP's programming environment/tool. If it is VSCode and OP is replacing in multiple files, neither will work. If it is Swift ([OP's previous question is a Swift question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71779901/3832970)), it won't work either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes you are right, this is of course only based on the capabilities of the engine, which is currenly unknown.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Then maybe you can write a solution that is working in swift if there is a tag added.

Comment: If it is really a Swift question, I will, the solution will be really nice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am fully confident that you will :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a look ahead for `=`:

```
\.(?=.*=)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/XRQbO2zRWyewij) working for all your examples.

The [look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=.*=)` asserts that there exists a `=` somewhere after the current position.

---

If you're expecting dots *and* equals after the dots all within the value, extend the look ahead to require 2 quotes after the equals:

```
\.(?=.*=.*".*")
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/XLr8fSFUdFKvaU).

This guards against:

```
"some.key" = "foo.bar=baz"
```

Comment: This will not work if there is a `=` anywhere on the right side of `=`. The values seem to be arbitrary texts and can include any symbols.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fine. look ahead extended. that should cover it sufficiently.

Comment: No, lookahead is not safe in this context. See [another case where it still fails](https://regex101.com/r/1Yqfvy/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes I know, but I'm happy with my regex and I'm betting 99% of people including OP are OK with it. There's a balance between a practical solution that covers all cases that are reasonably to be expected and a solution that covers every possibility in the universe no matter how unlikely they are. If I addressed your suggested input, I could go down one more level of the rabbit hole and escape the escape. And then we could go again after that. But why should we when it's not going to happen? Developers have a responsibility to spend their time wisely, not to chase ghosts.